# How can I get value of a background step parameter in a scenario step in gherkin c#?

Tags: c#, parameters, automation, automated-tests, gherkin

**C#**

I've :

```
Background: I am on the My Account screen
Given That I am on the Login screen
When I type this phone +44776222141815 number
And I type this pin **** number
And Tap the Sign In button
Then The main menu screen should be displayed in less than 5 minutes
When I Tap the My Account option
Then The My Account screen should be displayed
When I Tap the Change PIN option
Then The application should show the Change PIN screen

Scenario Outline: Change PIN - Successful
When I provide the Change PIN details <oldpin>, <newpin> and <repeatnewpin>
And Tap the Submit Button
Then The transaction should be passed in less than 2 minutes
```

Background steps are defined in another feature/scenario which are accessed here with the help of tags.

In the step definitions I want to get phone number value mentioned in a previous step i.e. **+44776222141815** in the last step of Scenario Outline which is ***Then the transaction ...***

Is there anyway to get that value?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. The usual way to share data between steps is to use [context injection](http://specflow.org/documentation/Context-Injection/):

> To use context injection, you have to
>
> 1. Create your POCOs (simple .NET classes) representing the shared data
> 2. Define them as constructor parameters in every binding class you need them
> 3. Save the constructor argument to instance fields, so you can use them in the step definitions